# How to parse UDP datagram to a Dart Class

Tags: c, dart, struct, udp, datagram

I am developing a Dart application. This app receives UDP packages from a socket. Here is an example of a datagram struct(sent from a C application):

```
struct DataLoggerMessage
{
   uint16_t loggerFlag;
   uint16_t eventOnOff;
   uint16_t generatedEventNumber;
   uint16_t systemPausedFlag;
   mainInput input;
   mainOutput output;
};

struct mainInput{
   float p1;
   int p2;
   double p3;
   ....
}

struct mainOutput{
   float p1;
   int p2;
   double p3;
   ....
}
```

I want to parse these comming struct to a Dart class like below:

```
class DataLoggerMessage {
   int? loggerFlag;
   int? eventOnOff;
   int? generatedEventNumber;
   int? systemPausedFlag;
   MainInput? mainInput;
   MainOutput? mainOutput;
}
```

My main problem is to determine right bytes. For example; first 2 bytes of the datagram is 'loggerFlag', but in the dart class 'loggerFlag' is 4 byte integer. Of course I can store 2 byte in an int. But I need a proper parser for whole struct. For example in C we can simply do this:

```
memcpy(ioStruct, value,  sizeof(DataLoggerMessage));
```

Is there a method in dart like above? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `ByteData` to create a memory block and then use the methods on this to set/get specific data using types with bit sizes: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html

Comment: thank you i will look at ByteData class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get a [`ByteBuffer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer-class.html), you can simply have:

```
var short_int_list = byte_buffer.asInt16List(0, 4)
data_logger_message.loggerFlag = short_int_list[0]
data_logger_message.eventOnOff = short_int_list[1]
...
```

similarly for a [`ByteData`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.6/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html) object, then you have things like

```
var byte_length = 2
data_logger_message.loggerFlag = byte_data.getInt16(0*byte_length)
data_logger_message.eventOnOff = byte_data.getInt16(1*byte_length)
```